# Diagonalizable Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T\circ T= I$ where $I$ is the identity map, then is $T$ always diagonalizable?

I am wondering if $T\circ T = I$ implies that $T=T^{-1}$ or that need not be the case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that we are working over a vector space defined over a field with characteristic $\neq 2$.

Note that the polynomial $$p(t)=t^2-1=(t+1)(t-1)$$ annihilates $T$. Hence the minimal polynomial divides $p(t)$ and is thus a product of distinct linear factors. Hence $T$ is diagonalizable.

If, however, we are working over a field with characteristic $2$, then the matrix
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
provides a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you so so so much!! Really appreciated.